# Trying to retrieve several elements by same ID from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a car database which stores several cars for each individual model, I am trying to retrieve all the cars for a specific model however my code is not working, where am I going wrong?

```
$ModelID = $_GET['model_id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Car WHERE ModelID = $ModelID");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{           
   echo $row["RegNumber"];
   echo $row["Colour"]; 
}
```

Comment: `WHERE ModelID = '$ModelID'`. But you should really read up on Prepared Statements

Comment: Yeah I pasted the code in wrong, that was already there

Comment: make sure that your $ModelID will contains a value try echo and check

Comment: As well as check that the variable it is the correct value controls the name of your database tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having error here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{           
   echo $row["RegNumber"];
   echo $row["Colour"]; 
}
```

you should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead.

Do not mix the functions of [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) & [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) API if your code is previously written in mysql api try to port it to mysqli or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).